# Why is it called a ratio scale?

Tags: self-study, scales, ratio

Can you provide a simple example that clearly explains- why ratio scale is called ratio scale?

Comment: See [Stevens 1946](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.103.2684.677) when you feel ready to do a little math to understand what ratio scale precisely means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an interval scale, the intervals are equal.

The increase in temperature from 10 degrees to 20 degrees is the same increase from 20 degrees to 30 degrees. The intervals are equal. That's not true for a scale of, say math ability. Is the difference in math ability between someone who scores 10 and someone who scores 20 the same as the difference in math ability between someone who scores 20 and someone who scores 30? What does 10 more points of math ability even mean?

But in a scale that's not ratio, the ratios don't make sense. You can't double 10 degrees and get 20 degrees, and call that twice as hot.

In a ratio scale, ratios make sense. 20lbs is twice as much mass as 10lbs. 1 minute is half of 2 minutes. (And if you're using temperature, you can use the Kelvin scale, which does have a true zero, and is ratio).

Comment: Can you please look into this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/573269/negative-marks-belong-to-which-scale) as well. I asked it but still awaiting response. I am new to DS, so, I have foundation level questions.

Comment: i agree with the comment from whuber. I don't think that question is answerable as asked. You should ask your lecturer what they meant.